# Jenkins Script Console: delete workspace folder including space in folder name

Tags: jenkins, groovy

here is my problem:
I deleted a project with the name "test_job 2".
The name includes a space.
Now the project is gone but the workspace folder is still there.

So usually I go to Jenkins Script Console and run:

```
println "ls -la /var/jenkins_home/workspace/".execute().text
println "rm -rf /var/jenkins_home/workspace/<folder name>".execute().text
println "ls -la /var/jenkins_home/workspace/".execute().text
```

But it doesn't work when the folder name includes space.
All the usual suspects also don't work and I also don't get any error messages.

Here is what I've tried so far without success in Jenkins Script Console.
If I connect to my local test jenkins via terminal it works.

```
"rm -rf '/var/jenkins_home/workspace/test_job 2'".execute()
```

Comment: The first instance wouldn't work because it considered `folder` to be the folder and `name` to be a separate command. However, the second instance looks fine. Try running it with `sh`